# Canvas JavaScript - Check if circle shape collides with pixeldata

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision, pixel

So, I want to check if a circle shape collides with any pixeldata that is not transparent in HTML5 Canvas.

To gather pixeldata, you can just do:

```
ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h)
```

And to check if point is in circle you just use pythagoras:

```
(x1-x0) * (x1-x0) + (y1-y0) * (y1-y0) < r * r
```

Where 0 is the center of the circle and 1 is the point's coords, and r is the circles radius.

Do you kinda have to loop trough all pixels or something?

Let's say:

```
Circles center is at: 300, 420
Circles radius is: 20
Canvas size is: 750 * 500 pixels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you'll only need to examine the image data within the circle's bounding box:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(c.x - c.radius, c.y - c.radius, c.radius * 2, c.radius * 2);
var pixels = imageData.data;
```

Then loop through that data, getting the color values and position:

```
var w = imageData.width;
var h = imageData.height;

var l = w * h;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var r = pixels[i*4]; // Red
    var g = pixels[i*4+1]; // Green
    var b = pixels[i*4+2]; // Blue
    var a = pixels[i*4+3]; // Alpha

    // skip to next iteration if the alpha of this pixel is 0
    if(a === 0) {
        continue;
    }

    // get the position of this pixel
    var y = i / w;
    var x = i - y * w;

    // check for collision and exit is there is one
    if(isInCircle(x, y)) {
        collision = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you on your way!

Comment: Was thinking to ensure a round value but probably superfluous. Will remove for clarity!

Comment: @imcg No, it's not superfluous. You will need to get an integer value for y, which at the moment you are not. If you use a floating point value for y then x will be all over the place.